# Failed to start lnd.service: Unit bitcoind.service not found. (lnd installation)

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network-daemon, bash

- I installed my bitcoind and lnd correctly.
- I put my `datadir=/mnt/vdb` to `bitcoind.conf` file and it allows me to start bitcoind with this command: `bitcoind -daemon`.
- As a final step, I want to learn `lnd`

  `sudo service lnd start`

  > Failed to start lnd.service: Unit bitcoind.service not found.

For me, I don't understand why it can't find `bitcoind.service` since I could run `bitcoind` without `--datadir` parameter.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Starting a service by hand doesn't mean that it has the proper `init.d` or `systemd` config files in place that it could be started with the `service` command.  In this case it looks like `lnd` was setup to assume that `bitcoind` was also a `systemd` service so it can make sure it is started first.  If you can't start `bitcoind` with the `service` command then something is missing.

1. Maybe you didn't install `bitcoind` correctly and didn't realize it.  Look at the files that were installed and see if anything got put into `/usr/lib/systemd/system/unit` or `/etc/systemd/system/unit.d/` directories.
2. Or `lnd` has expectations that have drifted from what `bitcoind` is providing over some period of time.  The "easy" work around is to modify the `systemd` config for `lnd` to no longer try to start `bitcoind`.